# How are parameters sent when I use instance variables in form_for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, form-helpers

I am little bit confused on how the parameters are sent to the controller through form_for in rails. I read `dealing with model objects` section in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html and tried to understand a bit but it did not help me much. 
Basically I have a form like below

```
<%= form_for @flow, url: '/create_flow' do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :action_id, value: @selected_action.id %>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>Flow name</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
    <% @selected_action.missed_call_flows.each do |flow| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= flow.name %></td>
        <td><code><%= flow.url %></code></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr class="form-group">
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Add a new flow ...", required: true %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate URL</button>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the corresponding controller is accessing parameters as `params[:missed_call_flow][:action_id]`

My question is from where did `params[:missed_call_flow]` come into play when it is not mentioned anywhere in the form. 
What I understood from the documentation is, when instance variable is given in form, for example it is `@flow` here, the params can be accessed as `params[:flow]`.
Then why in this code it is [:missed_call_flow] and not [:flow] ? Is this also one of the way of accessing because the controller name is MissedCallFlowController?

This is a sample application that I'm trying to understand for my project and the person who wrote the code is currently not available so posting it here for help. Let me know if my question is missing any details.

Comment: Is that the entire form? It looks to me like there might be an extra `<% end %>`.

Comment: perhaps your `@flow` is an instance of `MissedCallFlow` and not `Flow`. In short, you can name your instance variable with whatever name you use, but `form_for` uses the `class` of the object you're passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form_for` helper creates a form from a model object. If you've set up your Rails app in the conventional way, you will have (it appears) a file called `app/models/missed_call_flow.rb` that begins by defining `class MissedCallFlow`.

This file defines the model. It is the source of the `params[:missed_call_flow]` name, because it is the convention in Rails to name this data structure for the model.

As a generalization in programming, the variable name should not impact the functioning of the program. The fact that you have named your variable `@flow` is ignored by the inner workings of your program. It is a convenience to the programmer to be able to name your variable whatever you want.

I wonder if you are not seeing the model name you expect because `missed_call_flow` represents a join table between two other tables with models named `missed_call` and `flow`. You might be assigning an instance of this MissedCallFlow class to the variable `@flow` by mistake.

Comment: yeah, I have a model name as MissedCallFlow. But how does rails know that `@flow` is an instance of MissedCallFlow and not any other model ? Is it because of its location ie, is it because `@flow` or this form is created in MissedCallFlow controller and hence it assumes `@flow` belongs to MissedCallFlow model?

Comment: No, it's not an assumption. You'll find that the variable `@flow` is being set somewhere, probably in a controller file. It might look like this: `@flow = MissedCallFlow.new`

Comment: aah! got it, yeah its set in controller. Thank you so much for the detailed answer.